# Image/Video/Audio Succeed in Upload from Android to PHP but Can't open them - damaged/corrupted

Tags: php, android

I make this HTTP POST request in my Android application:

```
    private final String delimiter = "--";
    private final String boundary = "SwA"
            + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "SwA";
    private final String charset = "UTF-8";
    private final String lineSpace = "\r\n";
    private final String domain = (domain);

    private HttpURLConnection configureConnectionForMultipart(String url)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url))
                .openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="
                + boundary);
        return con;
    }

    private void addFormPart(String paramName, String value, DataOutputStream os)
            throws IOException {
        os.writeBytes(lineSpace + delimiter + boundary + lineSpace);
        os.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName
                + "\"" + lineSpace);
        os.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset
                + lineSpace);
        os.writeBytes(lineSpace + value + lineSpace);
        os.flush();
    }

    private void addFilePart(String paramName, File data, DataOutputStream os)
            throws IOException {
        os.writeBytes(lineSpace + delimiter + boundary + lineSpace);
        os.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName
                + "\"; filename=\"" + data.getAbsolutePath() + "\"" + lineSpace);
        os.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet \r\n");
        os.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineSpace);
        // os.writeBytes(lineSpace);
        os.flush();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(data);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        os.writeBytes(lineSpace);
        os.flush();
        fis.close();
    }

    private void finishMultipart(DataOutputStream os) throws IOException {
        // os.writeBytes(lineSpace);
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes(delimiter + boundary + delimiter + lineSpace);
        os.close();
    }

private class ObjectUploadRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final String _filePath;
        private final String _url = domain + "upload.php";

        public ObjectUploadRunnable(String filePath) {
            _filePath = filePath;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                HttpURLConnection con = configureConnectionForMultipart(_url);
                con.connect();
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                        con.getOutputStream());
                File data = new File(_filePath);
                addFilePart("data", data, os);
                finishMultipart(os);
                String response = getResponse(con);
                Log.i("BoxUpload", response);
                con.disconnect();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I catch it on my server with the script upload.php:

```
...
$dir = "/uploads/";
$target_path = $dir.basename($_FILES['data']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "file uploaded";
} else {
    echo print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Everything seems to succeed, in that a file with the correct size gets uploaded to my server, in the desired directory.  However, when I try to open the file, it seems to be damaged or corrupted in some way because it won't open in any application that I try. I'm uploading images=jpeg, videos=mp4, audio=mp4.  These files are all working on the client before upload. Am I missing something to encode the files correctly in the POST request? I've never done file uploads before, so I'd appreciate some advice...

**EDIT**

In case this is relevant, I've noticed that the files which I've uploaded have grown by ~100kb.  Maybe something's getting added to my binary data which is corrupting the file?

Comment: You're simply assuming uploads will never fail. Bad idea. **ALWAYS** check the `['errors']` parameter in $_FILES before you do anything else.

Comment: OK, I did a var_dump[$_FILES) and the error field shows 0 errors. Is this sufficient? I don't think there are any errors in the actual upload since a file of correct size is uploaded where I intend it to go. I just can't open it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem here.  That extra line that I commented out in addFilePart was actually necessary. I guess there needs to be two lines between the header info and the binary data in that part of the request. To be clear, it should look like:

```
private void addFilePart(String paramName, File data, DataOutputStream os)
        throws IOException {
    os.writeBytes(lineSpace + delimiter + boundary + lineSpace);
    os.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName
            + "\"; filename=\"" + data.getAbsolutePath() + "\"" + lineSpace);
    os.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet \r\n");
    os.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineSpace);
    os.writeBytes(lineSpace);
    os.flush();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(data);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    os.writeBytes(lineSpace);
    os.flush();
    fis.close();
}
```

Everything works great now!